# How to add AWS name servers in example.com domain to which are authoritative for ELB url?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

I have only two private ec2 instances running my website and they are attached to ELB with no auto scaling.

I have registered a domain example.com on third party domain registrar. My web site is heavily dependent on name servers. So, I want the list of name servers authoritative for the ELB URL which I can replace it with existing name servers present at third party domain registrar.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done with following and it worked

1. assuming that domain is registered on third party domain controller other than AWS route53
2. We can create hosted zone for the domain "example.com" in Route53
3. In "example.com" hosted zone, create an alias record for 'www' with ELB URL as the target.
4. Now there will be 4 default AWS name servers for hosted zone "example.com"
5. Now copy these name servers and replace it with the existing name servers present at third party domain controller.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is slightly confusing.

Your options are a [CNAME](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/using-domain-names-with-elb.html) within your current DNS provider, or AWS Route53 with an alias record.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a CNAME record to map from www.example.com to your ELB
  endpoint.
- Establish a redirect from the root domain example.com to
  www.example.com to avoid the risks associated with root domains and
  A-records. Set Route 53 servers as the nameservers for your domain.
- Route 53 uses different terms than standard industry parlance so this
  guide has non-trivial variance from other guides

.